# draw.io downloads file on every save

Tags: app.diagrams.net

While creating a diagram in draw.io, pressing ctrl+S keeps downloading the file multiple times, how to set it so that it saves the work but does not download the file on every save.

Comment: What URL are you using? What browser and version?

Comment: Using in brave browser [This is the URL](https://app.diagrams.net/)

Comment: It's a web app and Brave doesn't have File API support. Where did you select to save to in the opening splash screen?

Comment: I selected a subfolder in one of the drives.. even after doing that, the browser downloads on every save.

Comment: Browsers do not have filesystem access, unless they implement the File API. Brave has not implemented that, so you will be prompted for download location every time. See https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/11407